# What was Euron's motivation for this fight in the Season 8 episode, "The Bells"?

Tags: game-of-thrones

What did he possibly have to gain from this?

The city was lost. Euron had lost his improbable aiming skills. He could have just run but instead he tried to fight and kill a non aggressive Jaime. 
Why?

Comment: Need for extra screen time?

Comment: or just escape with the boat, as Cersei and Jaime would have done

Comment: He wanted to be the man who killed Jamie Lannister. Jamie was super-famous and renowned as one of the greatest fighters alive. (It’s quite possible that people in general hadn’t figured out he wasn’t much use as a fighter after losing his hand.) Euron wanted to be the guy who took him down.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite That's essentially the reason Euron gives, but I think the question is still *why*. Becoming "the man who kills Jaime" doesn't seem to have been a priority for Euron prior to that. He wanted to build a military and conquer people. This new goal of his just kinda came out of nowhere.

Comment: @MishaR maybe, although the “finger up the bum” conversation he had with Jamie suggests that he enjoys messing with the guy at least. And his casual admission to Yara that he’d just sail home if it looked like Cersei was going to lose suggests that he wasn’t all that fussed about actually winning the war.

Answer (score 40):

A few reasons:

#### Jaime is competition for Cersei

If he plans to wed the Queen to make himself King, he can't have her lovers hanging around. Especially one that has historically been the father of all her children.

#### Jaime is a traitor at this point

Last time he left King's Landing, it was to fight with Daenerys against the Night King. This is a treachery that shouldn't go unpunished. Now Euron may be miscalculating on this point, since I'm not sure Cersei would have *actually* been thrilled to have Jaime cut down, but he's still a traitor.

#### "I'm the man who killed the Kingslayer"

Obviously Euron thinks highly of himself, and loves for others to as well. If he beat Jaime frickin' Lannister, he'd be famous for it. He's *the Kingslayer*, after all, and well known to be one of the best fighters around. Sure, he may be down a hand, but details get left out over time. As it is, nobody will ever know what happened in that fight, but if he had won handily, then he'd tell the story his own way.

#### He didn't think he'd lose

Jaime is one-handed, and Euron sees himself as a badass. There's no way he thought he was going to lose this fight.

#### He's kinda just an asshole like that

This is Euron. He *loves* to fight, and he's never really liked Jaime anyway. Even disregarding the rest, why *not* have it out with him here and now?

Comment: _"Jamie is a traitor at this point"_ Whilst true this might not be 100% true in universe at this point because he is also now a traitor from Dany's side to go back to Cersei's so she might have had him back after a bit of a squabble.

Comment: Sure, but he hadn't been forgiven by Cersei *yet* is the point. She did have Bronn try to kill him (along with Tyrion), after all. Like I said, I don't think the man who *actually* killed Jamie would be thanked, but Euron may or may not know this.

Comment: I'm agreeing with you, just splitting hairs and being a bit pedantic is all :)

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot That's the Stack Exchange mantra.

Comment: Great answer, but one possible addition to the third point: Euron is (was) Ironborn, and they have a strong cultural tradition of accomplishing feats of daring and combat prowess (see Theon's ideas about celebrating his taking Winterfell with Robb). It's more than *just* fame, for someone from the Iron Islands.

Comment: @Upper_Case Other Westerosi celebrate these things as well (see the Kingsguard White Book, for example), and famous knights are mentioned throughout the series. True, the Ironborn may value it more, but either way, I meant more than "just fame". The whole "he's the guy that did the thing", internal pride, honor, all that jazz. But he's *definitely* cocky enough that he'd want to be that guy anyway :)

Comment: @Geobits Of course! I wasn't meaning that he was unique, only that that was another, specific factor which might have motivated Euron in particular.

Comment: @Geobits 1 and 2 don't really apply based on what Euron says to Jaime. "That is the sounds of a city dying."  He appears to have known it was over, and so being king to Cersei means nothing.

Comment: @kuhl He also says "If you kill another king before you die they'll sing about you forever," along with "If I win I'll bring your head to Cersei so you can kiss her one last time". He still see himself as king, and a (small) possibility of winning here, I think. Either way, I'd take most of what he says to Jaime here as posturing, or just general swordfight trash talk.